# UILabel text not changed of another method other than ViewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel

UILabel is not changed out of ViewDidLoad method. How can I change in any method of Label?

Label text is changed:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
label.text = @"testing";
}
```

But, here label is not changed

```
- (void)anothermethod
{
label.text = @"testing";
}
```

Also have to ensure that this change of method(`Anothermethod`) other than viewDidLoad.

Comment: make sure that your method must be on main thread.

Comment: how you are calling `anothermethod` ?

Comment: did u add [self anothermethod]; in viewDidLoad ?

Comment: Yes, I add self anothermethod]; in viewDidLoad. Thanks your answer, but I fixed my problem. I want to define a static method and able to change in the value of the Label.

Answer (score 0):

1) Please check t hat in other method , your label is not nil.if it is nil means there is not any object in memory.

2) If you are getting nil then try to set property and then check with self.label.text = @"your text"

3) Call this method where you want, as suggested in comment you have to call it manually as [self anothermethod];.viewDidLoad will call automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `anothermethod` is called before the view is loaded so `label` is just `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks your answer, but I fixed my problem. I want to define a static method and able to change in the value of the Label.

```
@implementation ViewController
static UILabel *label;

- (void)anothermethod
{
label.text = @"testing";
}
```

This time it is working correctly

Comment: Making things static isn't a stable solution. You should recheck if your label object isn't empty before you call your method to fill its text.